# Update a Progress Bar (located in window) from a Page that is called inside a frame of that window

Tags: c#, wpf

As the question states, I Have My Window here with a progress bar

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progress_bar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="3" Margin="148,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="868" Foreground="#FF3B79D3" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#FF9DB0D8" x:FieldModifier="public" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

and Code Behind with Some Attempts to allow the update of progress bar.

Here I have Set the Progress Bar to Public

Tried a Property Getter Setter

Tried a delegate

```
namespace dcn
{
    /// Interaction logic for dash.xaml
    public partial class dash : Window
    {
        public static ProgressBar pr;
        public dash()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fwinitializing();
            progress_bar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            pr = progress_bar;
        }
        private void UpdateProgressBar(int i)
        {
            Action action = () => { SetProgress(i); };
            progress_bar.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
        }
        public int prgbar
        {
            get { return (Int32)progress_bar.Value; }
            set
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(value);
                pr.Value = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                progress_bar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                tmp.Content = "Processing......" + value + "%";
                UpdateProgressBar(Convert.ToInt32(value));
            }
        }
        private void SetProgress(int i)
        {
            progress_bar.Value = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Now on my page that is called inside a frame of the above window. Here I am running a Multiple Insert Query to a MDB File using a Background Worker that works Correctly and also Updates the progress bar if placed in this page. But I want to update the progress bar of the Above Window.

```
namespace dcn
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for mach_sync.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class mach_sync : Page
    {
        CABLE.Cable_app sending = new CABLE.Cable_app();
        string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\xyz.mdb";
        //string pass = "";
        string[] data = new string[10];
        BackgroundWorker cust_to_mdb;
        public mach_sync()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cust_to_mdb = new BackgroundWorker();
            // Some Background Worker Code
        }
        void cust_to_mdb_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            dash da = new dash();
            da.prgbar = e.ProgressPercentage;
            da.progress_bar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.ProgressPercentage);
            da.tmp.Content = "Processing......" + da.prgbar.ToString() + "%";
            da.UpdateLayout();
            //progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            //Console.WriteLine("Processing......" + da.prgbar.ToString() + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions would be Awesome. I have started c# with this Application only. I am a Full Time Web Developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question right, then this is the answer:

```
//get the window hosting the page
var window = Window.GetWindow(this) as dash;
// check for null
if (window != null) {
    //set value of the progressbar
    window.prgbar.Value = 75;
}
```

Not related to the question but i thought i'd mention that you don't need to use Convert.ToInt32() everywhere since the values you are trying to convert are already of that type.

Comment: Ah! You are Awesome Thank You... A lot